# Where do I put 'helper' methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

In my Ruby on Rails app, I've got:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if request.post? and params[:role_data]
      parse_role_data(params[:role_data])
    end

  end
end
```

and also

```
module AdminHelper
  def parse_role_data(roledata)
    ...
  end
end
```

Yet I get an error saying `parse_role_data` is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helpers are mostly used for complex output-related tasks, like making a HTML table for calendar out of a list of dates. Anything related to the business rules like parsing a file should go in the associated model, a possible example below:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.parse_role_data(roledata)
    ...
  end
end

#Call in your controller like this
Admin.parse_role_data(roledata)
```

Also look into using (RESTful routes or the :conditions option)[http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html] when making routes, instead of checking for `request.post?` in your controller.

Comment: Hmmm... but I have an admin controller but not an admin model.

Comment: You can easily just define the model with no child class, ie. `class Admin`. If the file doesn't exist, just make a file called `admin.rb` in the models directory.

Comment: Now I get "undefined method `parse_role_data' for Admin:Class".

Comment: Are you defining the method with `self` in front of it, like `def self.parse_role_data(roledata)`?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be accessing the parse_role_data through the AdminHelper?

**Update 1:** check this
 http://www.johnyerhot.com/2008/01/10/rails-using-helpers-in-you-controller/

Comment: While that's a useful tip for using niceties like the formatting-related helpers provided by ActionView, integral business code really does belong in the model.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of if you're trying to create a UI for adding roles to users.  I'm going to assume you have a UsersController already, so I would suggest adding a Role model and a RolesController.  In your routes.rb you'd do something like:

```
map.resources :users do |u|
    u.resources :roles
end
```

This will allow you to have a route like:

```
/users/3/roles
```

In your RolesController you'd do something like:

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])
    @role = @user.roles.build(params[:role])
    if @role.valid?
        @role.save!
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

This will take the role params data from the form displayed in the new action and create a new role model for this user.  Hopefully this is a good starting point for you.

Comment: True, but hopefully it'll highlight what he's doing wrong.  Wanting to use helpers in your controllers is normally an indication that you're not doing enough in the model.